# Workaround for the missing NVL() in JPA 1.0

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql, nvl

is there a workaround for the missing NVL() function in JPA 1.0 (Eclipselink 1.1.x)?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no standard workaround.  With EclipseLink 2.1 `nvl()` will just be supported through JPQL. But with EclipseLink 1.1, it seems you'll have to use EclipseLink Expressions, in particular `Expression.ifNull()`. See [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/NVL-in-EclipseLink-td19493072.html) and [Bug 219814](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=219814) for the details.